# Pivot for Unknown number of values in description- SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

May some one please help me how to get the result in SQL SERVER 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TABLE') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN;
    DROP TABLE #TABLE;
END;

CREATE TABLE #TABLE
(
[Generic Name] varchar(15),
[Description]varchar(15)
)

INSERT #TABLE

SELECT 'RESISTOR',  'POWER' UNION ALL
SELECT 'RESISTOR',  'Type' UNION ALL
SELECT 'RESISTOR',  'DESIGN' UNION ALL
SELECT 'RESISTOR',  'Material' UNION ALL
SELECT 'OTHER',  'Other' UNION ALL
SELECT 'OTHER',  'Material'; 

DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@query NVARCHAR(MAX);


select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Description) 
                    from #TABLE
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT [Generic Name], ' + @cols + ' 
            FROM
            (
                SELECT [Generic Name], [Generic Name] AS [BaseName], [Description]
                from #TABLE
            ) DS
            pivot 
            (
                COUNT([BaseName])
                for [Description] in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

            SELECT @query

execute(@query)
```

[image]

This will show you the `count` (but if you have only one record for each description it will be only true/have or false/not have) of each generic name.

Comment: i am not sure but i am gertting error like : The number of elements in the select list exceeds the maximum allowed number of 4096 elements.

Comment: You are allowed to `SELECT` only 4096 columns This is SQL Server limitation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server - this means you have more then 4096 unique descriptions. You can try to select them on parts - first 4096, then the second, etc and returned them on parts.

Comment: any way to handle this scenario. kindly suggest

Comment: If you are returning this data in `client side` application, you can separated it and return in parts using different row sets.

Comment: Thank You Very Much: will it be possible to see result like for each Generic Name , Design, Material,other, Power and TYPE as Value of the column under Column Name as Desc1, Desc2....DescN

Comment: You want different heading name for the columns, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below change in your query

```
set @query = 'SELECT  ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select [Generic Name], Description
                from @TABLE
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                MAX([Generic Name])
                for Description in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
```

Since you are pivoting the records, there won't be a column **[Generic Name]** -- I Don't see any such column in the table structure so I'm assuming that you need to column **Base Name**-- so, the @Cols parameter is enough

Please Check the [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/605c8/3) here